# How to show all page navigation bar button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

i am working Ecommerce app  and i want to show all page basket button .. for user click any page user able to check all product added list then she able to check from there ..

my navigation bar make programmatically:

```
  let viewController = DishViewController()
  viewController.shopCategory = shopCategory
  let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)

  self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Currently i am doing my to show  basket every page viewDidload() :

```
   func setupNavigationBar(){

        // back button without title
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

        //set titile
        self.navigationItem.title = "Your Order"

        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "busket"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        //show the Edit button item
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `extension` to `UIViewController` and implement the function their.

```
extension UIViewController {
   func setupNavigationBar(title: String) {
        // back button without title
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

        //set titile
        self.navigationItem.title = title

        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "busket"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        //show the Edit button item
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
   }
}
```

and in your `ViewControllers's ViewDidLoad` method simply call

```
setupNavigationBar(title: "Your Order")
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: if i trying to do . some page have 2 button (busket , search) or 1 button (busket) . what can i do for that ?

Comment: You can do it by passing button types as parameters along with title and create a logic to display according to it. e.g func setupNavigationBar(title: String, buttons: [String]){ }. Then call  setupNavigationBar(title: "Your Order", buttons: ["busket","search"])

Comment: I have ViewControllers inside a TabViewController that is inside a NavigationController. I would like to have my navigationItem in all the controllers, but I can't see it? It's under the navigation ba

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BaseViewController and inherit your view controllers form it. 
On your BaseViewController you have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

    //set titile
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your Order"

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "busket"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    //show the Edit button item
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

}
```

Then all your view controllers would have the button as long as they call super.viewDidLoad() of course